# Show text box when press push button

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How to show a text box when I press a push button?

for example I have variable

```
set(handles.edNama2,'String',nama);
```

Value of nama is Elisabeth

My Push Button variable is DataPribadi

I want the text box to show with the personal data of Elisabeth

[image]

Comment: I don't understand; what is wrong exactly?

Comment: I want a texbox to show when I press Data Pribadi, Elisabeth is a value that come from Classification button, not from Data Pribadi

Comment: Ok so you want to create a textbox and display the name in it? Isn't this what the line of code above do?

Comment: Yes, set(handles.edNama2,'String',nama); is the line code before Data Pribadi Button. I don't have any space to show the personal data of Elisabeth, that's why I want to show a text box when I press Data Pribadi Button

Comment: So you want to add another `textbox` (than the one showed in your example), in order to display extra informations. Is that correct ? If yes, would the textbox be in the same figure or in a new figure ?

Comment: Are you looking for a pop-up window? If so, use the `msgbox` command: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/msgbox.html

Comment: yes, it's right, a pop up window and extra information in a new figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates text box:

```
handles.edNama2 = annotation('textbox', [your_position_of_the_text_box_here]);
set(handles.edNama2, 'String', ['He needs ', num2str(10), ' $USD!!!']);
```

This opens new message box for you:

```
msgbox(['I want ', num2str(1e+6), ' $USD']);
```

So you can put your info in the `[]`, remember to convert to `String` type.